# Can't get daily step count from Google Fit API

Tags: android, google-fit

I am new to the Google Fit API. I am trying to get the the daily step count from the API but with no luck.

I've been up and down the official documentation and Stack Overflow, 
but it seems like Google made big changes to the API in 2018 and 
so most things are outdated, including Google's own tutorials (posted in 2018). 
A few places that have updated documentation provide snippets of code,
and because of that I have no idea how to use them.

Here is my code that connects to Google Fit:

```
    FitnessOptions fitnessOptions = FitnessOptions.builder()
            .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
            .addDataType(DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
            .build();

    if (!GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this), fitnessOptions)) {
        GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(
                this, // your activity
                GOOGLE_FIT_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE,
                GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this),
                fitnessOptions);
    } else {
        accessGoogleFit();
    }

private void accessGoogleFit() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(new Date());
    long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);
    long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();


    DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
            .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
            .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
            .build();



    Fitness.getHistoryClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
            .readData(readRequest)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DataReadResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DataReadResponse dataReadResponse) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess()");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"onSuccess()",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),dataReadResponse.getBuckets().get(0).getDataSets()+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    tvLastRun.setText(dataReadResponse.getBuckets().get(0).getDataSets()+"");

                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onFailure()", e);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"onFailure()",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            })
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataReadResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataReadResponse> task) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onComplete()");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"onComplete()",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: what's the error you're getting in logcat

Answer (score 0):

```
08-27 13:10:39.488 1996-2723/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/InstanceID/Rpc: No response android.os.ConditionVariable@33657c3a
08-27 13:10:39.488 1996-2723/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/GLSUser: [AppCertManager] Failed to get security token.
    java.io.IOException: TIMEOUT
        at vpw.b(:com.google.android.gms@11947270:40)
        at vpw.a(:com.google.android.gms@11947270:47)
        at vpt.b(:com.google.android.gms@11947270:11)
        at vpt.a(:com.google.android.gms@11947270:29)
        at fvt.b(:com.google.android.gms@11947270:4)
        at fvt.a(:com.google.android.gms@11947270:55)
        at fvr.a(:com.google.android.gms@11947270:8)
        at fvn.a(:com.google.android.gms@11947270:1)
        at fvm.a(:com.google.android.gms@11947270:10)
        at com.google.android.gms.auth.account.be.legacy.AuthCronChimeraService.b(:com.google.android.gms@11947270:7)
        at faq.call(:com.google.android.gms@11947270:3)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at mwc.run(:com.google.android.gms@11947270:26)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at nbl.run(:com.google.android.gms@11947270)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
08-27 13:10:39.505 1996-2723/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/ConfigurationChimeraPro: Got null configs for com.google.`enter code here`android.gms.common_auth
08-27 13:10:39.524 1996-2723/com.google.android.gms.persistent I/Auth: [ReflectiveChannelBinder] Successfully bound channel!
```